# Apache server seems to fall asleep after not being used for a while

Tags: apache2

I'm having some issues with a web server. It is not used a lot yet (mainly by me now), but will be used as a live server hosting a couple hundred/thousand Wordpress sites soon.

I'm currently having the issue that when the webserver isn't used for a bit (some minutes) it seems to 'fall asleep'. From then the first request takes an awfull long time to process and after that it runs smoothly for a bit.

The server (VPS) it's on is dedicated to being a webserver, so apache (/mysql) should be top priority.
Does anybody know what I can do to improve this?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the machine is just going into some kind of powersave mode.  It's unlikely it has anything to do with Apache at all.

Comment: The machine is up and running fine. I'm accessing it via RDP and there's is no problem there. The machine is alive...

Comment: what sort of worker is being used ? Could indicate that when idle workers are being killed off and when requests start to come in again, apache spawns new workers before handling the request to them ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue finally solved itself when we started getting more visitors to the server, keeping it alive.